# Difference between validates_format_of and validates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

We can validate email by doing:

```
validates :email, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
```

or

```
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :on => :create
```

What is the difference between the 2 approaches. Is one approach better than the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference between those two forms. The first is just a convenient shortcut for being able to specify multiple validations on a single attribute. For example, let's say you wanted to ensure that an email is valid but also unique. Using the second form in your example, this would be written

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email
validates_format_of :email, with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX
```

Or, it could be written more succinctly using `validates`

```
validates :email, uniqueness: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
```

What's also nice about using `validates` is that you can mix default validations with your own custom validations with a single call to `validates`. More information [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates).

Comment: One thing I'd add and it's why I use `validates` more often and that's because of the ability to chain attributes:  

 `validates :first_name, :last_name, format: { with:  /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/ }`  I find this to be really useful.